# Authenticating WebAPI call using AAD

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory

Recently we migrated our website to AAD. Website is working fine after AAD migration. But the issue is, we are generating one word document and that document contains hyperlink (web api call to generate the another attachment dynamically) to open another attachment.

We are unable to validate that request because web api call from word application.
Is ther any way to acheive this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Did you want to generate the another attachment dynamically which require authentication after users click the hyperlink in the document.

How did you want to authenticate the dynamically? Based on my understanding, if the web API also protect bu Azure AD using the [Authentication / Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview), we can enable to redirect the unauthenticated request to Azure AD like figure below:

[image]